# How do I uninstall the old version of Postgres on CentOS 7?

Tags: postgresql, installation, delete, centos

I just installed Postgres 9.6 on CentOS 7.  However when I run

```
[root@server tmp]# /usr/bin/psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.23
```

It still seems to be pointing to my old version.  How do I uninstall the old version (or figure out what its called) without harming the new version?

Comment: Besides the version of the software that becomes the default from now on, what do you want to happen to the data (the databases in the old installation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer version of Postgres will be in `/usr/pgsql-9.6` (or a similar location) so you can simply use [the alternatives command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) to make this one the default.

Comment: Will the "alternatives" command uninstall the old version?  One of the objectives is to free up some disk space as well.

Comment: Do `rpm -qa|grep postgres` to find out which package it is then `yum remove` the packages you don't want. Also `yum whatprovides /usr/bin/psql` might help find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the running processes `ps -ef|grep post` you can see which version of postgres is currently running. All you have to do is:

```
1. Stop the postgres version you want to delete / uninstall.
2. Delete the 'bin' and 'data' directories of the postgres version you just stopped.
3. If you are using tablespaces, delete the contents of your tablespace location as well.
4. Remove entries of the postgres version from file '/etc/postgres-reg.ini' and all the postgres version specific files from '/etc/init.d' location.
```

BTW, if you have used the one step installer to install the postgres, it creates an `uninstall-postgresql` file just before the `bin` directory location. You can use that to uninstall as well, it will automatically perform above steps.