# Recommended procedure to remove old files after major version PostgreSQL database cluster upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I (successfully) followed the upgrade procedure in  [§18.6.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-PGDUMPALL) of the PostgreSQL Manual to upgrade a PostgreSQL database cluster from 10.7 to 11.2 (running Fedora 29). I would like to remove the old tablepaces (some of which are user-defined tablespaces) and other legacy files to reclaim space not needed from the old cluster.

There are two approaches I’ve considered:

1. Connect to the old database cluster as `postgres` and run queries against the pg_catalog system tables to DROP tables, tablespaces, databases, etc.
2. Run `find -L /path/to/tablespace/root -type d -user postgres -iname “PG_10_*” exec rm -rf {} \;` to remove directories in the tablespace locations (note the new tablespaces share the same root directory as the old ones)

After either (1) or (2), I’d remove the old `PGDATA` directory.

Is there a preferred approach (including any methods not mentioned)?

Note, this is distinct from the following post: [How do I uninstall the old version of Postgres on CentOS 7](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206189/157801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be very careful about here is whether you’ve done a pg_dump+pg_restore or a pg_upgrade.

It sounds like you’ve done a pg_dump+pg_restore based on the docs section you’ve linked to.

In that case it should be safe to completely remove the old data directory, including table spaces, as you have a full copy of the data in the data directory of the new cluster.

If you have used pg_upgrade that is *not* safe to do (neither are the two methods you’ve described), because some of the files are hard-linked from the old to the new cluster.

Edit: As pointed out in a comment, the latter is only true if you have used the “--link” option for pg_upgrade.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` will only use links if run with the `--link` option. If that was **not** used, it's totally safe to remove the old directory.

Comment: Confirm that `pg_upgrade` *not* used (on account of the custom tablespaces). Appreciate the answers and will give `option 2` a go.